Length of the product of two elements of the subregular two-sided cell in the affine Weyl group of type A
The affine Weyl group of type $A_n$ can be described as follows. It is the group of all permutations $\sigma: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that $\sigma(i+n)=\sigma(i)+n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n (\sigma(i)-i) = 0$. The elements $s_i$ $(i = 0,\dots,n-1)$ are given by
$$s_i(j)=\begin{cases}
j+1, \text{ if } j \equiv\ i \ (\text{mod } n); \\
j-1, \text{ if } j \equiv\ i+1 \ (\text{mod } n); \\
j, \text{ otherwise.}
         \end{cases}
$$
For any integer $i$ define $[i]$ to be the remainder obtained when we divide $i$ by $n$. An element of the affine Weyl group lies in the subregular two-sided cell if and only if it is of the form $s_{[i]}s_{[i+1]} \dots s_{[j-1]} s_{[j]}$ for some integers $i \leq j$ or of the form $s_{[i]}s_{[i-1]} \dots s_{[j+1]} s_{[j]}$ for some integers $i \geq j$.
Question: can one estimate from below the length of $vw$ (hopefully by a function of lengths of $v$ and $w$) where $v$ and $w$ are elements of the subregular two-sided cell? The most important case I care about is when $v$ and $w$ are of the form $s_{[i_1]}s_{[i_1+1]} \dots s_{[j_1-1]} s_{[j_1]}$ and $s_{[i_2]}s_{[i_2+1]} \dots s_{[j_2-1]} s_{[j_2]}$ where $i_1 \leq j_1$ and $i_2 \leq j_2$.

Have you tried writing out uw as a permutation (in general if possible, and otherwise in examples) and using the characterization of length in terms of inversions as described in Section 8.3 of the Bjorner-Brenti book?  That might give you an idea what bound you are trying to prove, and then maybe you could prove the bound using manipulations of reduced words.
